# how to add php code to http-server which I installed from npm?

Tags: javascript, php, npm, httpserver, simplehttpserver

I am very new to npm .. 
currently, I got started with http-server . 
I installed  `npm install HTTP-server -g` and now I can have a running server ( my website now has "html, and javascript" codes )

In order to add php to my website, I will need to install php .. 
How can I install php to http-server?
So I could simply add  on my html part

Comment: Node.js cannot run PHP.  You should write Node.js code instead.

Comment: Not tried this but there is a node.js binding to php : **[look here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-php-server)**

Comment: @SLaks The only reason I want to use php is to connect to a database and get data fast and efficient ... I thought using php would make it faster on server side Vs on the client (js).  What do you recommend? The website just draw graphs from data from db

Comment: You should write all of your server-side code in Node.js.